# How to match nested text prefixed with spaces in sed or grep

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to match nested text, including the line immediately prior to the nested text with sed or grep.

An example of what I'm working with:

```
pattern3
    abcde
    fghij
pattern3
pattern1
    abcde
    fghij
pattern1
pattern1
    klmno
pattern1
pattern3
    abcde
pattern1
    pqrst
patterh3
    fghij
```

Note that there are always four (4) spaces prefixing the nested text.  Also, there may or may not be nested text after a matching pattern.

I'm interested in all `pattern1` lines, plus the lines following `pattern1` that are proceeded by spaces.

The output I'm looking for is:

```
pattern1
    abcde
    fghij
pattern1
pattern1
    klmno
pattern1
pattern1
    pqrst
```

I got close with:

```
sed -n '/^pattern1/,/^pattern1/p' data.txt
```

But it seems to skip nested text after the right hand side `pattern1` match, and move onto the next iteration.

I also tried `sed -n '/^\"pattern1\"$/,/^\"pattern1\"$/p' data.txt | sed '1d;$d'` with no luck either.

Comment: sed is for doing `s/old/new` which is not what you are doing, and grep is for doing `g/re/p` which is not what you are doing. So the immediate response to `How to match nested text prefixed with spaces in sed or grep` is - you don't as there are other tools that are far better equipped for the job.

Comment: @EdMorton Excellent point, and completely understandable when you form it that way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/{p;:x;n;s/^    .*/&/;p;tx}' file
```

or simplified:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/{p;:x;n;p;/^    /bx}' file
```

Output:

```
pattern1
    abcde
    fghij
pattern1
pattern1
    klmno
pattern1
pattern1
    pqrst
```

Comment: Nice. But I'd still use the awk solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/pattern[23]/{flag=""} /pattern1/{flag=1} flag'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '/pattern[^1]/{flag=""} /pattern1/{flag=1} flag'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here.

```
awk '
/pattern[^1]/{        ##Checking condition if a line is having string pattern with apart from digit 1 in it then do following.
  flag=""             ##Nullifying variable flag value here.
}
/pattern1/{           ##Checking condition here if a line is having string pattern1 then do following.
  flag=1              ##Setting value of variable flag as 1 here.
}
flag                  ##Checking condition if value of flag is NOT NULL then print the line value.
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This is great, and I appreciate the explanation.  It's far better than my version: `awk '/.*/ { doReset=1 } /^pattern1/ { doReset=0; active=1; print } /^    .*/ { doReset=0; if (active) print } /.*/ { if (doReset) active=0 }' data.txt`.  I'll consider this a backup incase I can't acquire a `sed` solution.  :)

Comment: Looks like this sort of works - if there's any non-matching lines after the last instance of `pattern1`, then it leaves them behind.

Comment: @CzarMatt, please give me example here and I will edit code then.

Comment: I've updated the example in the question to reflect.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^[^ ]/{f=/^pattern1$/} f' file
pattern1
    abcde
    fghij
pattern1
pattern1
    klmno
pattern1
pattern1
    pqrst
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\S/h;G;/pattern1/P;d' file
```

Store the current pattern in the hold space and append it to each line. If the current pattern is pattern1, print the current line and/or delete the current line.